# Langlands dual of torus

Tags: algebraic-groups, langlands-conjectures

Let $T$ be a split torus over a field $k$. Then the dual torus $\hat{T}$ is defined to be the unique torus such that
$$
X_*(T)=X^*(\hat{T}),
$$
where the left hand side is the cocharacter lattice of $T$ and the right hand side is the character lattice of $\hat{T}$.

1. Is there any way to concretely write down $\hat{T}$ in terms of $T$?
2. Is there any explicit isomorphism between $X_*(T)$ and $X^*(\hat{T})$?

Comment: One can take $\hat{T}= \operatorname{Hom}( X_*(T), \mathbb G_m)$, I guess.